# Não é possível utilizar diretiva v-for sobre prop passada ao componente do Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Passagem de valores com VueJS</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <my-ul>
                <my-li></my-li>
            </my-ul>
        </div>

        <template id="my-li">
            <li v-for="item in items">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </template>

        <template id="my-ul">
            <ul>
                <my-li :items="['Bala', 'Chocolate']"></my-li>
            </ul>
        </template>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script>

            Vue.component("my-li", {
                template: "#my-li",
                props: ["items"],
            });

            Vue.component("my-ul", {
                template: "#my-ul",
                data: function() {
                    return {

                    }
                },
            });

            var app = new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                data: {
                    message: "Hello Vue"
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Se tento somente verificar se `prop` `items` estpa sendo passada dessa forma:

```
<template id="my-li">
    <li>
        {{ items }}
    </li>
</template>
```

Tenho como saida:

```
[ "Bala", "Chocolate" ]
```

Mas ao tentar aplicar a diretiva `v-for` simplesmente recebo uma tela em branco, mas não consigo identicar onde estou errando. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esta tendo problemas para renderizar pois esta usando DOM Template, de uma olhada na [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Ressalvas-na-Analise-do-Template-DOM) sobre as particularidades de DOM Templates.

Basicamente, você precisa usar o atributo `is`. Como `<ul>` aceita apenas `<li>` como tag filho, você escreve a tag `<li>` e diz no atributo `is` qual o componente que você quer renderizar ali.

Veja os exemplos, o `meu-ul` é a correção do código que você apresentou e o `meu-ul-2` é o que eu acredito que você gostaria de usar, com a API de [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

```js
Vue.component('meu-li', {
  template: '#meu-li',
  props: ['item']
});

Vue.component('meu-ul', {
  template: '#meu-ul',
  props: ['itens']
});


Vue.component('meu-ul-2', {
  template: '#meu-ul-2',
  props: ['itens']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      itens: ['Bacon', 'Banana', 'Nutella']
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <meu-ul :itens="itens"></meu-ul>

  <meu-ul-2 :itens="itens">
    <template slot="linha" slot-scope="slot">
      <meu-li :item="slot.item" />
    </template>
  </meu-ul-2>
</div>

<template id="meu-ul">
  <ul>
    <li is="meu-li" v-for="item in itens" :item="item"></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<template id="meu-li">
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
</template>

<template id="meu-ul-2">
  <ul>
    <slot name="linha" v-for="item in itens" :item="item"></slot>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Giovane agradeço pela resposta ajudou muito.